# gRPC Golang example server runs 2 processes?

Tags: go, grpc

I'm just starting out with gRPC using Go. I started the server using:

`go run greeter_server/main.go`

I ran the associated client and all worked as expected. I did a naive `ps -aux | grep greeter` and then killed the associated process. I restarted the server and received an error that the port, 50051, was already in use. I ran `ps` again and didn't see the server process. I then ran:

```
lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep 50051
main      52229 rich_youngkin    3u  IPv6 0x8f763a4a32733ba7      0t0  TCP *:50051 (LISTEN)
```

That was confusing. I then ran another `ps` grepping for that pid:

```
ps uax | grep 52229
rich_youngkin    52229   0.0  0.0  4986700   6384 s000  S     3:29PM   0:00.01 /var/folders/9z/lyfc9l3500b_111_x89br7bh0000gn/T/go-build096317928/b001/exe/main
```

I killed this process and restarted the server. A little smarter now I ran a slightly different `ps` and I see the 2 processes:

```
ps aux | grep "/main"                                                                               1 ✘    15:49:25 
rich_youngkin    60758   0.0  0.0  4985676   6356 s000  S     3:49PM   0:00.01 /var/folders/9z/lyfc9l3500b_111_x89br7bh0000gn/T/go-build997935897/b001/exe/main
rich_youngkin    60735   0.0  0.1  5113896  20876 s000  S     3:49PM   0:00.86 go run greeter_server/main.go
```

Why are 2 processes running? What are their purposes?

Thanks,
Rich

Comment: One is the go run command and one is the actual binary that go builds and executes. If you add the -f flag you'll see that main is a child of go run.

Comment: Or just build a binary with `go build` and run that directly.